# Staggered Layout in UICollectionView (iOS 10 and above) - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image: StaggeredLayout]Hi,
This is my `dataSource` for `UICollectionView`

`var dataSource = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"]`

I am trying to do a staggered layout like shown in the pic below:

My `numberOfRows` are fixed as `3`

Second Row should contain one element more than the first and third. `count` of `dataSource` will always be 3n+1.

I used a small hack and got this layout below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
        if indexPath.item == 1{
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
       
        return CGSize(width: 180, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
         if section == dataSource.count - 1{
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        } else{
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -70)
        }
       
    }
```

[image: What I have now]

Comment: So please show us your layout code.

Comment: added the code snippets

Comment: @vamshi-krishna: Whats the issue?

Comment: Extra cell should be shown in the middle row. I am able to get that on first row